# How to get Twilio Usages data every few minutes?

Tags: java, php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

Requirement: I need to monitor the Twilio account and subaccount usages in near real-time.
Any solution in java, php, python or even curl will do for me.

Twilio provides [Usage Records API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api/usage-record) and allows some [subresources](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api/usage-record#list-subresources) which contains [`Today`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api/usage-record?code-sample=code-todays-calls&code-language=Java&code-sdk-version=9.x) but that returns all data from the start of that day till the nearest current time. I am unable to find anything in the documents that would retrieve only usages of the last minute or last 10 minutes or even between two time constants. The Usage API accepts two dates but not time.
Hoping someone out there has a solution to offer.

Comment: Not sure what data exactly you need to get, but maybe you can use UsageTriggers instead? https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api/usage-trigger

Comment: @CBroe I need the data given by the usages records API such as SMS/Voice usages (including related bill charged) in the last n minutes and fees charged in the last x hours.

Comment: Also the usage-trigger has its finest resolution as once per day, which does not satisfy my requirement.

Comment: it's not like the prices change every other day. if you know how to monitor every action that occurs you can easily estimate the charges down to the penny more or less.

Comment: Assuming the Usage Records API is real-time, updating throughout the day, you could ping it every ten minutes and subtract the previous values to get the number within the last ten minutes (i.e., if there were 47 messages ten minutes ago and there are 55 now, 8 occurred in the last ten minutes). This is a little better than querying every ten minutes for the last ten minutes; if the query for just ten minutes is early, something might get double counted, if it's late, something could get skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Responses from the endpoint don't return any properties that you can use to filter out older records, unfortunately. The only suggestions I have are to persist the results in the response to a database table or cache, where each record has some kind of unique identifier and then query the data store for the newer records using the identifier to filter out the older/previously retrieved records.